# paragraph overlap on smartphone

Tags: html, css, smartphone, paragraph

I'm using a bootstrap template and getting paragraph overlap only on smartphone (iPhone 6, Safari).  Works fine on browser even while shrinking the browser window to minimum size to test.  Overlap occurs after 2 lines on phone.

There is no max height in the css.  This is the css for paragraph:

```
.about-grid p {
    padding:0 0 0.5em 0;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
}
```

You can also [see the full web page online](http://sandiegodogtrainers.org/2015/san_diego_dog_trainers_allTrainers.html).

Answer (score 1):

It´s quite simple to fix:

on line 1279 of style.css you have a breakpoint declared

```
@media (max-width: 320px)
```

and on line 1391 you have this class:

```
   .about-grid p {
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 1em;
   }
```

The height is forcing your text blocks to be only 50px high, and since you don't have an "overflow: hidden;" the text overflows and ends up overlapping on everything else. it also happens if you make your browser window really small, not just on smartphones.

All you have to do is remove that height declaration. If you need it for some reason just add a new class and make it more specific.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: sure, where do I do that??

Comment: @beeuu just click the Tick symbol near the up/downvote button